# Is there any solution for mix language problem in tesseract 4.1.1?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I want to covert image to text with tesseract engine. Input image has two language(persian and english). When I use tesseract multi language feature(fas+eng), converted text has many error.
For example:
[image: input image]

output:

> BERT Joo‏ و استفاده از آن
> در این گزارش به تعریف مفاهیم مورد نیاز برای شناخت مدل 7۳11 می‌پردازيم و نحوه استفاده از
> آن را برای تحلیل متن توضیح می‌دهیم.

Should I train model with persian and english text?

Comment: What's your tesseract command used?

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z. tesseract image.png out -l fas+eng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must update to latest version of tesseract OR fas trainned data.

I use this version of tesseract:

```
# tesseract.exe --version
tesseract v5.0.0-alpha.20191030
 leptonica-1.78.0
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.3) : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0
 Found AVX
 Found SSE
 Found libarchive 3.3.2 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.2.3 bz2lib/1.0.6 liblz4/1.7.5
```

And also I use this commit version for fas train data:
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/blob/cdd8a9ec438fc0b9f21635466196fe1c05efca16/fas.traineddata

And I use this command:

```
tesseract.exe image.png out -l fas+eng
```

So as you can see in here, We have this correct text:

```
مدل ‎BERT‏ و استفاده از آن
در این گزارش به تعریف مفاهیم مورد نیاز برای شناخت مدل ‎BERT‏ می‌پردازيم و نحوه استفاده از

آن را برای تحلیل متن توضیح می‌دهیم.
```

Also see this image:
[image]